# how to align sub tags in parent tag

Tags: css

i'm trying to make a "call to action" button.I have a parent  tag and in it there are two tags,first

tag is for description second  tag tag is for the button.But the description text destroys the button alignment. How can i align these tags properly?
screenshot:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<div id="call-to-act">
<p>Description</p><a href="http://esakademi.com/ADB/" class="call2act">Button Text</a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div#call-to-act {
    background: #fff;
    width: 95%;
    height: 75px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 72px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 72px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: inset 10px 10px 72px -28px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

div#call-to-act a.call2act {
    -moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #ffffff;
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ededed), color-stop(1, #dfdfdf) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ededed 5%, #dfdfdf 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dfdfdf');
    background-color:#ededed;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft:6px;
    border-top-left-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright:6px;
    border-top-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright:6px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:6px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:6px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:6px;
    text-indent:0;
    border:1px solid #dcdcdc;
    display:inline-block;
    color:#777777;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size:15px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:normal;
    height:44px;
    line-height:44px;
    width:120px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-align:center;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    right: 2px;     
}
div#call-to-act a.call2act:hover {
    background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #dfdfdf), color-stop(1, #ededed) );
    background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #dfdfdf 5%, #ededed 100% );
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#dfdfdf', endColorstr='#ededed');
    background-color:#dfdfdf;
}
div#call-to-act a.call2act:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;    }
```

Thank you!

Something like:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~               |
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  +---------+  |
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  |         |  |
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  +---------+  |
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~               |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

is what i'm looking for.

Comment: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/L3gtx6qe/) for use here!

Answer (score 0):

---

To make this:

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~               |
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  +---------+  |
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  |         |  |
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  +---------+  |
| ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~               |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

## Solved

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/FAwku/79/)

which uses the display: flex;

```css
/* flex method beautiful */

.top6 {
  background-color: blue;
  height: auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.in6 {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.in62 {
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="top6">
  <div class="in62">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum
  </div>
  <div class="right">

  </div>

  <div class="in6">
    <button>ButtonText
      <button</div>
  </div>
  <br>
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/FAwku/80/) with your styling

Comment: centering the button and touching not to eachother, is that possible?

Comment: yes i found this http://theme-fusion.com/avada/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/browsers.jpg actually my wish is also somethink like that please see purchase button(second one) there

Comment: but your demo is different than you drawing

Comment: getting there. But the drawing is what you're looking for, yes?

Comment: exactly! it is like your drawing

Comment: your solution is with div tags, it is nice but mine is something like this <div><p>description</p><a>button</a></div>

Comment: the contents of your `<p>` can easily be placed in to the first `div`, and your button can be placed into the second `div`?